# Programatically Validating Xml Input Prior To Using XmlSerializer Deserialization?

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I have an Xml Schema that I created myself and generated the corresponding C# classes using the Xsd.exe tool. My application then reads in (deserializes) an Xml document into the generated type(s).

Here is the code I use to deserialize:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyConfig));
TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(fileName);               
MyConfig config = (MyConfig)serializer.Deserialize(textReader);            
textReader.Close();
```

XmlSerializer is very forgiving when it comes to parsing Xml. The Xml can be invalid with respect to the schema but it can still be deserialized.

What I want to do is validate the Xml prior to deserializing the file. I have Google'd how to do this and it seems straight forward.

The issue/concern I am having is I want to deliver a single .EXE file but if my program does runtime Xml validation against an Xml Schema document won't I also have to include the .xsd as part of my delivery *and* make sure this .xsd file is always in the same (relative) directory to the executable?

Perhaps there is a way I could *embed* the Xml Schema document into my compiled application that way I have don't have to find/read it from disk?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can just mark the file as a resource, or just drag it into a resx if easier. There are countless examples on using embedded resources

Comment: I have done some work with embedded resources. I have several labels/buttons that need to change their icons (images) at runtime so I mark the images as embedded resources then call myAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName) to get the resource as a stream.